# How to draw a window frame

Tags: android

I am trying to buid an user interface to allow to present information to a user.

The information would be grouped in windows related to the category that might look kind of like this:
[Crude drawing of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9lZw.jpg)

It should have a place to put a title, a button I can set to different options and an inner layout to display the information.

Is there a similar object I can use in android or how would I go about building one?

EDIT:
The final result for a phone should be something like [Drawing of a phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShNOX.jpg)

EDIT2: Since i feel like I wasnt clear enough in my question I changed the title. I know how to place a list of elements on the screen, what I wonder is how to make those elements be framed by a rectangle with rounded corners that has a field for the title and a customizable button

Comment: In android studio start a new project and select basic activity. You will get a window just like in your drawing. There will also be a FloatingActionButton which you may delete

Comment: But i need it to have multiple of that kind of window

Comment: for multiple window you can use different layouts and populate them using list view or recyclerview

Comment: Yeah, but how do I generate the window frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [ReyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) for displaying a list of items.

Look at [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) for displaying each "window" item.

Look at [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) for how to make a layout.

Comment: The cardviews make almost the result I wanted to make, just wondering if there is any way to outline the cardview with a colored line.

Comment: Cardview has some padding and shadowing effects, so adding an outline may not look quite right on a card view. You might try replacing the CardView with just a regular FrameLayout that has a bit of padding and a background color of the outline, then the background color will appear as an outline.